# Почему не происходит переход на страницу в Spring MVC?

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

Вторые сутки бьюсь с проблемой возврата страницы в контроллере Spring MVC. С клиента приходит JSON-объект, к нему добавляются данные текущей сессии. Объект отправляется на другую страницу.

```
@PostMapping(value = "controller", consumes = "application/json")
public String controller(@RequestBody SomeDto someDto, Authentication 
authentication, ModelMap modelMap) {

String username;
try {
      username = authentication.getName();
} catch (Exception e) {
      String message = "Unauthorized user";
      LOG.warn(message);
      return "login";
}

UserDto userDto = userService.getUser(username);
someDto.setUser(userDto);

modelMap.addAttribute("someDto", someDto);
return "another-page";
}
```

Метод отрабатывает, данные приходят, но не происходит return (не происходит перенаправления на login в случае, если вход в систему не выполнен, или на another-page, если пользователь авторизован).

Что я делаю не так? Как правильно реализовать замысел?

**UPD:** если я правильно понимаю, вместо перенаправления на другую страницу он возвращает эту страницу в теле запроса.

Comment: А Вы создали вообще эти страницы?

Comment: Разумеется. Контроллер возвращает код этих страниц (html) на фронт. Можно сделать редирект на фронте, но тогда теряются данные. Необходимо, чтобы контроллер возвращал другую страницу.

Comment: Во-первых, `value = "/controller"`

Comment: А во-вторых, проверка на авторизацию делается так: `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().isAuthenticated()`. В двух словах, когда пользователь успешно проходит авторизацию `Spring Security` создает обьект `Authentication` и кладет его в `SecurityContext`. Если пользователь не авторизован: `Authentication = null`.